# How to allign two plots in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following matplotlib code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Time of day values
time_of_day = [
    "00:00", "01:00", "02:00", "03:00", "04:00", "05:00", "06:00", "07:00", "08:00",
    "09:00", "10:00", "11:00", "12:00", "13:00", "14:00", "15:00", "16:00", "17:00",
    "18:00", "19:00", "20:00", "21:00", "22:00", "23:00"
]

# Electricity load values in W
electricity_load = np.array([
    5460, 177, 163, 745, 770, 1049, 1090, 868, 277, 3117, 3416, 1383, 1551, 4324, 969, 431, 703, 1201, 898, 4969,7839, 259, 410, 617
])

# Convert electricity load values to kW
electricity_load_kW = electricity_load / 1000

# Price values in Cent/kWh
price_values = [
    27.1,  26.5,  26.0, 25.1, 26.6, 27.5,  34.4, 51.3, 45.3,  44.3, 44.3,  41.3,  38.1,  35.5,
    33.9,  37, 41.4,  48.6,  53.4,  48.6,  43.4, 38.7, 37.8,  27.4,
]



# Create subplots within the same figure
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, 1, figsize=(12, 10), sharex=True)

# Plotting the bar diagram
ax1.bar(time_of_day, electricity_load_kW[:len(time_of_day)], color='#FFD700', edgecolor='black')

# Labeling the first plot
ax1.set_ylabel('Electricity Load (kW)', fontsize=18)
ax1.grid(axis='y', linestyle='--', alpha=0.7)

# Plotting the step line plot
ax2.step(time_of_day, price_values, where='post', color='limegreen', linewidth=6)

# Labeling the second plot
ax2.set_xlabel('Time of Day', fontsize=18)
ax2.set_ylabel('Price (Cent/kWh)', fontsize=18)
ax2.grid(axis='y', linestyle='--', alpha=0.7)

# Adjust x-axis limits to eliminate empty space
ax1.set_xlim(time_of_day[0], time_of_day[-1])

# Increase thickness and rotation of x-tick labels
for ax in [ax1, ax2]:
    ax.tick_params(axis='x', which='both', labelsize=14, width=2)

# Set x-tick labels with rotation and horizontal alignment
plt.sca(ax1)
plt.xticks(rotation=45, ha='right')

plt.sca(ax2)
plt.xticks(rotation=45, ha='right')

# Tighten the layout
plt.tight_layout()

# Save the figure and plot it
plt.savefig('C:/Users/wi9632/Desktop/temp_combined.png', dpi=100)
plt.show()
```

So I have a bar diagramm on the upper part and on the lower part there is a step line plot. What I want is that the horizontal lines of the bar diagramm and the step line plot are at the same x-position such that they are alligned. This means that the values for the x-label ticks (00:00 to 01:00, 01:00 to 02:00 etc.) should be at the same position which is currently not the case.

Comment: By the way, you should be working with datetimes for the x-axis, not strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to center the bar plot on `edge`:

```py
# Plotting the bar diagram
ax1.bar(time_of_day, electricity_load_kW[:len(time_of_day)], color='#FFD700', edgecolor='black', align='edge', width=1)
```

This gives the following plot (I hope this is what you were searching for):

[image]

Comment: Thanks Cesar for your answer. When adding your line, the problem is that there is empty space on the left and right of the x-label- ticks (so before 00:00 and after 23:00, unlike in your picture). How can I remove that

Comment: You can set `width` to 1, I edit the answer

Comment: Does not change anything unfortunately. There is still empty space before 00:00 and after 23:00

Comment: This is strange, have you removed your old line before adding the new one? What is your python version?

Comment: Thanks Cesar for your comment and effort. I really appreciate it. Yes, I have removed the old line before adding the new one and my python version is 3.11

Comment: Oh I understood what happened ^^ You applied both @umar's answer changes and mine, I obtained also the white space doing that. Take your original code and simply apply my line: the white space appeared because `ax1.set_xlim(time_of_day[0], time_of_day[-1])` was removed.

Comment: Thanks a lot Cesar for your answer and effort. I really appreciate it. I upvoted and accepted your answer.

Comment: Hi Cesar it's me again. I have a small follow up question for a small adjustment. At the moment there is  no empty space at all on the very first and very last bar such that the rims of the bars are also the rim of the whole figure. Can I add some very small empty space between the bar on the very left and the one on the very right? Further, the bars are all connected to each other. Is there a way how I can add empty space between each of the bars?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Any comments to my last comment about the empty spaces around the bars? I'll highyl appreciate every further comment from you

Comment: Yes you can add some spaces on the boundaries, just play with `ax1.set_xlim(left_limit, right_limit)`. And if you want to add spaces between bars, just set the parameter `width` in `ax.bar()` to something below one

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Unfortunately, both of your advised adjustments do not really work. When changing the `width` in ax.bar(), the bars are not centered anymore on the x-axis ticks. When changing `ax1.set_xlim(time_of_day[0] , time_of_day[-1])` the plots don't look good. I tried `ax1.set_xlim("00:00 ", "23:10")` or `ax1.set_xlim("-00:10 ", "23:10")` and it just looks bad. What I want is just to have a little bit of empty space on the very left and the very right of the diagramm

Comment: I also tried `ax1.set_xlim(time_of_day[0] - 0.5, time_of_day[-1] + 0.5)` but this yields an error `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'float'`. Further, regarding the bar widths I tried to use `align=center` in `ax1.bar(time_of_day, electricity_load_kW[:len(time_of_day)], color='#FFD700', edgecolor='black', align='center', width=0.9)`. Now the bars are centered, however, the very right and the very left bars are only being displayed halfed. Do you have any idea how I can tackle those 2 issues?

Answer (score 1):

To align the x-axis ticks for both plots, you can use the set_xticks method on one of the axes and set the ticks to be the positions of the bars.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Time of day values
time_of_day = [
    "00:00", "01:00", "02:00", "03:00", "04:00", "05:00", "06:00", "07:00", "08:00",
    "09:00", "10:00", "11:00", "12:00", "13:00", "14:00", "15:00", "16:00", "17:00",
    "18:00", "19:00", "20:00", "21:00", "22:00", "23:00"
]

# Electricity load values in W
electricity_load = np.array([
    5460, 177, 163, 745, 770, 1049, 1090, 868, 277, 3117, 3416, 1383, 1551, 4324, 969, 431, 703, 1201, 898, 4969,7839, 259, 410, 617
])

# Convert electricity load values to kW
electricity_load_kW = electricity_load / 1000

# Price values in Cent/kWh
price_values = [
    27.1,  26.5,  26.0, 25.1, 26.6, 27.5,  34.4, 51.3, 45.3,  44.3, 44.3,  41.3,  38.1,  35.5,
    33.9,  37, 41.4,  48.6,  53.4,  48.6,  43.4, 38.7, 37.8,  27.4,
]

# Create subplots within the same figure
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, 1, figsize=(12, 10), sharex=True)

# Plotting the bar diagram
ax1.bar(time_of_day, electricity_load_kW[:len(time_of_day)], color='#FFD700', edgecolor='black')

# Labeling the first plot
ax1.set_ylabel('Electricity Load (kW)', fontsize=18)
ax1.grid(axis='y', linestyle='--', alpha=0.7)

# Plotting the step line plot
ax2.step(time_of_day, price_values, where='post', color='limegreen', linewidth=6)

# Labeling the second plot
ax2.set_xlabel('Time of Day', fontsize=18)
ax2.set_ylabel('Price (Cent/kWh)', fontsize=18)
ax2.grid(axis='y', linestyle='--', alpha=0.7)

# Set x-axis ticks for the step line plot to match the bar plot
ax2.set_xticks(ax1.get_xticks())

# Increase thickness and rotation of x-tick labels
for ax in [ax1, ax2]:
    ax.tick_params(axis='x', which='both', labelsize=14, width=2)

# Set x-tick labels with rotation and horizontal alignment
plt.sca(ax1)
plt.xticks(rotation=45, ha='right')

plt.sca(ax2)
plt.xticks(rotation=45, ha='right')

# Tighten the layout
plt.tight_layout()

# Save the figure and plot it
#plt.savefig('C:/Users/wi9632/Desktop/temp_combined.png', dpi=100)
plt.show()
```

Comment: It might be helpful if you only showed the relevant changes rather than the entire code.

Comment: @Umar: 
Thanks Umar for your answer. When adding your line, the problem is that there is empty space on the left and right of the x-label- ticks (so before 00:00 and after 23:00). How can I remove that

Comment: do the following
# Set x-axis limits to eliminate empty space
ax1.set_xlim(time_of_day[0], time_of_day[-1])
ax2.set_xlim(time_of_day[0], time_of_day[-1])

# Alternatively, you can use the plt.xlim() function
plt.xlim(time_of_day[0], time_of_day[-1])

Comment: Thanks a lot Umarfor your answer and effort. I really appreciate it. I upvoted your answer.